# What am I doing wrong running a jquery function on each item of a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a line separator that will have a bit of text as a title and then follow the text with a strike-through to the edge of the page.  I thought I was writing the bit of jquery properly to call the function on each instance of my separator div but apparently I'm not.

Here's what I thought it should be:

```
$(".separator").each(function() {
    var linewidth = 706 - $(".s-text").width();
    $(".s-line").width(linewidth);
});
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/WY7tL/

Comment: You never do anything with the `.seperator` values.

Comment: This should be done using CSS.

Comment: How would it be done with only css? I tried setting a width of 100% on the s-line div and a couple other things and after messing around with paddings and margins I figured it was too kooky.  Plus I wanna try to do little things like this in jquery to try and get better :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Solution

You must specify which `.s-text` element you want to select, in this case, the **child** of the selected `.separator`.

---

### Explanation

`$.each()`, or `$('selector').each()` will loop through all the elements corresponding to the selector query that you provide it.

Each time it goes into the loop, the specific element **corresponding to the index of the array of corresponding elements** is selected and assigned to the variable `this`.

`this` is a DOMElement, not a JQuery object. This is why we put it within parenthesis, calling the JQuery (`$`) object on it: `$(this)`.

---

#### JavaScript/jQuery

```
$(".separator").each(function() 
{
    var linewidth = 706 - $(this).find(".s-text").width();
    $(this).find(".s-line").width(linewidth);
});
```

#### Pure JavaScript

```
var sep = document.getElementsByClassName('separator');
for (var i in sep)
{
    if(sep[i].nodeType==1)
    {
        var linewidth = 706 - sep[i].querySelector('.s-text').offsetWidth;
        sep[i].querySelector('.s-line').style.width = linewidth+"px";
    }
}
```

---

### [JQuery Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/WY7tL/3/)

### [Pure JavaScript Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/WY7tL/6/)

## [Performance comparison](http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-getelementsbyclassname)

Comment: Beat me by a few seconds. This.

Comment: @JeffNoel, explain to OP the use of '.each()' to perform some kind of 'while loop' and the necessity to **target** desired element for every 'loop'. This way OP will learn what was 'wrong' with his coding.

Comment: @Jared No problem, I just hope it's clear enough for everyone that might face the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/WY7tL/1/

You have to call `$(this).children('.class')`
Look at the code in the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the relevant element from inside your `.separator` by calling `find()` on it

```
$(".separator").each(function() {
    var linewidth = 706 - $(this).find(".s-text").width();
    $(this).find(".s-line").width(linewidth);
});
```